# Sum SymPy expression over NumPy array

Tags: python, numpy, sympy

So, if I do this

```
import sympy as sp
import numpy as np
u = np.random.uniform(0, 1, 10)
w, k = sp.symbols('w k')
l = sum(1 - sp.log(k + w) + sp.exp(k + w) for k in u)
```

I get what I want (a symbolic sum over `u` as a function of `w`). However, it would be much more useful to write

```
f = 1 - sp.log(k + w) + sp.exp(k + w)
l = sum(f for k in u)
```

But then I get

```
10*exp(k + w) - 10*log(k + w) + 10
```

What's going on? Is there a way to get the sum I want? (SymPy has several ways of summing over integers, but I haven't found one for arrays) (Version: Python 2.7.6, NumPy 1.8.1, SymPy 0.7.4.1)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that `f` is not being evaluated for each `k`. Try this out:

```
sum([f.subs(dict(k=k)) for k in u])
```

and it will give you the right result. Where `subs()` is being used to force the evaluation of `f` for each value of `k`.

Comment: @Mauricio great... since you are new here: don't forget you can also upvote the answers and questions of you would like to.... ;)

Answer (score 0):

Making f a function that returns the resulting calculation is what needs to happen here to make it work the way you have it.

```
f = lambda k,w : 1 - sp.log(k + w) + sp.exp(k + w)

l = sum(f(k,w) for k in u)
```